# Better way to find text, select to start of paragraph, and reformat

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I'm writing a macro in Word to find an open parenthesis, select from that character to the start of the paragraph, and then reformat the selected text into small caps. Fair warning, I know nothing about VBA and I hack these macros together from examples I find online.

The last part of the macro moves the cursor to the start of the next paragraph so that I can run it again. I'd like to loop it, but I haven't figured out how to set a stopping point for the loop yet.

The following macro works, but there has to be a better way to do it. This method results in a lot of screen flicker and takes forever to run.

```
Sub References()
'
' References Macro

'this part selects text until it finds an open parenthesis
Dim flag As Boolean
flag = True
While flag = True
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, _
    Extend:=wdExtend
    'checks the last character to see if its a open parenthesis
    If Strings.Right(Selection.Range.Text, 1) = "(" Then
        'if it was an open parenthesis the loop flag will end
        flag = False
    End If
Wend

'this part reformats the text
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Size = 12
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .SmallCaps = True
        .AllCaps = False
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
        .Spacing = 0
        .Scaling = 100
        .Position = 0
        .Kerning = 1
    End With

'this part moves the cursor to the beginning of the next paragraph
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdParagraph, Count:=1

End Sub
```

Comment: Use ScreenUpdating False/True to eliminate screen flicker https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.screenupdating

Comment: What is your reformatting doing - just changing the font or font size?

Comment: The reformatting is changing a few things, including both font and font size, but the most important part is putting it into small caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, using Find (which is way faster than testing every character):

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "("
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    i = i + 1
    .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.Start
    .Font.SmallCaps = True
    .Start = .Paragraphs.First.Range.End
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " instances processed."
End Sub
```

Comment: This works a little too well! Apologies, I should have provided more information in my question. If there are multiple open parentheses in a paragraph, I only want to apply the formatting to the text before the first one. That's why I had the macro skipping to the next paragraph at the end.

Comment: Code revised. Try it now.